Restore image size in Teams?
From yesterday to today (28 June, just rebooted) it looks like a Teams update decided to reduce image size for all posts (large pic showing relative sizes):

They were all different sizes, so there was some variation, but they now all fit the same area. All posts now have wasted white space on the right.
Is there anything that can be done so that they use maximum size within the available area?
